# Grouping entries using spark query

Tags: pyspark, group-by, sql-order-by, apache-spark-sql

I want to group the entries and want to get the total count of that as the output from the following data:

```
OccDate     Mne 
19-09-2018  A_sub1_123             
19-09-2018  A_sub2_123
19-09-2018  A_sub1_345
15-09-2018  A_sub1_123
15-09-2018  A_sub1_234
16-09-2018  A_sub2_234
```

Desired Output:

```
 Date        subsm   cnt
    19-09-2018   sub1    2     
    19-09-2018   sub2    1
    16-09-2018   sub2    1
    15-09-2018   sub1    2
```

I have tried the following query:

```
RDD = sparkAnalytics.sql("SELECT CONCAT(day(OccDate),'-',month(OccDate),'-',year(OccDate)) AS Date,Mne,Count(Mne) AS cnt FROM fs WHERE Mne LIKE '%%' GROUP BY Date,Mne ORDER BY Date DESC")
```

But I am not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not added error in your question.

I presume, you have defined SparkSession as "sparkAnalytics" instead of "spark" in your code. If not please check it.

Further there is a mistake in your query, i.e. instead of  "group by Date", you need to write "group by CONCAT(day(OccDate),'-',month(OccDate),'-',year(OccDate))"

Answer (score 0):

Try this on `dataframe`

```
df.groupBy(col("occdate").alias("date"),split(col("mne"),"_")[1].alias("subsm")).agg(count("*").alias("cnt"))
```